# How to move around a matriz in Assembly language using SI and DI as pointers?

Tags: string, assembly, input, text-editor

I'm trying to create a simple text editor but I'm not sure how to save user input into strings. How do I move and control the positions within each string? Also, how do I control when to go to the next string using SI? So far I have :

```
matriz:

mov si, 0
mov si, offset direc    ; for directions 

mov di, 0
mov di, offset fila1    ; [si+0] for 1st row
mov word ptr[si], di
add si, 2

mov di, offset fila2    ; [si+2] for 2nd row
mov word ptr[si], di
add si, 2

mov di, offset fila3    ; [si+4] for 3rd row
mov word ptr[si], di
add si, 2

mov di, offset fila4    ; [si+6] for 4th row
mov word ptr[si], di
add si, 2

mov di, offset fila5    ; [si+8] for 5th row
mov word ptr[si], di
add si, 2

ret
```

...........................

```
write:
mov cx, 1
cycle:    
        mov ah, 2h          ; character output
        int 10h             ; display character in dl   

        mov ah, 1h          ; keyboard input
        int 21h             ; read character into al

        cmp al, 27          ; ESC
        je fin          

        cmp al, 0   
        je compararSpecialKeys

        mov byte ptr [di], al
        mov cl, dl          ; to not lose value of posX
        mov dl, al          ; to be able to print
        mov ah, 2h          ; character output
        int 10h             ; display character in dl

        mov dl, cl
        inc dl              ; to move a position
        mov posX, dl        ; update posX
        cmp posX, 38        ; border limit
        je nextline

inc di
loop cycle
jmp start

ret
```

---

```
nextline:
mov dl, 1
mov posX, dl    ;update posX
inc dh
mov posY, dh    ;update posY
add si, 2
call write
```

---

```
posX db 1 dup(1)    ; dl = posX -> controls column
posY db 1 dup(1)    ; dh = posY -> controls row
xlimit dw 38        ; number of columns
ylimit dw 24        ; number of rows    
direc db 36 dup(42) ; 42 is ASCII for space
fila1 db 36 dup(42)
fila2 db 36 dup(42)
fila3 db 36 dup(42)
fila4 db 36 dup(42)
fila5 db 36 dup(42)
```

Comment: How do I use the SI pointer instead, and add another variable pos db to point to each "position" of the string??

Comment: I am trying to use SI as a direction pointer to five strings, but how can I use DI to move inside each string? Also, once a string is "filled", how can I go the next direction that SI points to?

Answer (score 1):

```
.loop:
    mov ah, 7
    int 21h
    cmp al, 27  ; ESC
    je finish   ; that will call fin

    mov ah, 0
    int 16h     ; for special keys
    call comparar

    jmp .loop
```

This part of code would do better in a loop, as you want to read multiple inputs, not just one. Also, `comparar` now requires a `ret` at the very end of its operations.

```
moveUp:
    mov dl, posX    ;actualizar coordinates
    mov dh, posY
    dec dh      ; posY -- 
    mov posY, dh
    jmp prntCrs     ; print cursor
```

I'm not sure whether this shouldn't be

```
moveUp:
    mov dl, byte [posX]    ;actualizar coordinates
    mov dh, byte [posY]
    dec dh                 ; posY -- 
    mov byte[posY], dh
    jmp prntCrs            ; print cursor
```

With `posX` and `posY` declared as

```
posX: db 0
posY: db 0
```

to store values.